# Laravel 5.3 Pagination - ErrorException in Collection.php line 432

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, syntax-error

Every time I try to setup my pagination:

> Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()

My controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = DB::table('products')
        ->where('product_group_id', '=', 1)
        ->paginate(15)
        ->get();

    return view('product.index', [
        'products' => $products,
    ]);
}
```

My view:

```
{{ $products->links() }}
```

What goes wrong here?

Comment: Off-topic but `return view('product.index', compact('products'));` is a bit more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `->get()` here. `->paginate()` gets your records from the database and returns a collection of those 15 items.

When you're running `->get()` here you're attempting to run it on the collection that is returned which expects a `$key` and is used to get a specific item out of a collection.

You should do this:

```
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->where('product_group_id', '=', 1)
    ->paginate(15);

return view('product.index', [
    'products' => $products,
]);
```

or with Eloquent

```
$product = Product::where('product_group_id', '=', 1)
    ->paginate(15);

return view('product.index', [
    'products' => $products,
]);
```

**Note:** I have put the filters before the `paginate()` call to ensure that the where clause is part of the database query rather than trying to filter the resulting collection/paginator

Comment: Thanks! There's just one little problem; `Method links does not exist`

Comment: Have you tried using `->render()` instead of `->links()`? Can you supply the output of a `dd($products);` please?

Comment: `->render()` doesn't work, but `Collection {#301 ▼
  #items: array:15 [▶]
}`

Comment: It seems that it's not returning a Paginator instance, which contains the `links` and `render` methods. I'm not sure why. Is there any particular reason you're not using Eloquent?

Comment: I just tried the same code(for different model of course) on my machine and `->links()` give me proper output. I am on Laravel 5.2, not sure what is wrong here

Comment: Actually I am using Eloquent.

Comment: You're using the query builder, I'll give you an example with eloquent in my answer. I don't see why the query builder is returning a collection rather than a paginator though, it should work. Can you post your updated code please?

Comment: @Doga could you tell us what `get_class($products)` is?
`

Comment: @Vivek I've putt `get_class($products);` under my `$products` query within my controller, but it doesn't show any output in the view.

Comment: @Doga wrap it in a `dd()` or `echo` it out. It will likely be `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. Please update your question with your updated code so we can see what you have, there might be something we can't see causing it

Comment: @Doga you could try in REPL. `php artisan tinker`. Or you could log the value using `Log::info(get_class($products))` and check the contents of `/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: @Jonathon ideally, I am hoping to see `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator"
`

Comment: @Vivek yes I know, but the likely result will be a collection, which is where the problem lies

Comment: @Jonathon I've tried it with Eloquent now and it worked! But there's something I left out in my question (controller). I actually filter these products depending on a product_group_id. Now it's just showing all the products. But the $products->links() work!

Comment: @Doga Good. I thought that would be the case. If you had included more code in your question or posted your updated code, I would probably have spotted it.

Comment: @Jonathon Ah, I mistook that you were expecting Collection, sorry

Comment: @Doga you should ideally put the `->where()` before the before the `->paginate()` if you want the `where` to be applied to the database query. The `where` in that code is filtering the paginator/collection that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `paginate()` method on a `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` object, [You will get an instance of `\Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1620). That itself does not have a `get()`-Method, but the `Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator` it extends has a [magic `__call()` function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php#L508) which forwards the call to the underlying Collection.

Now, `Illuminate\Support\Collection` *does* [have a `get()` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L3842), but it takes the key of the element you want to get out of the Collection as an argument, hence the error you get.

Now, I suppose what you actually want to achieve standard pagination with links for page numbers and "forward" and "back" buttons. If so, you should just stick to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination): Get the data just the way you did, just leave out the `get()`, then display it in a view the way its shown [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view).

**EDIT**: Just read about the `Method links does not exist` error you get. That is indeed strange. `Builder::paginate()` definitely returns an Instance of `LengthAwarePaginator` which itself definitely has a `links()` method.

Is there perhaps some more code that is relevant to this problem which you havent shown us yet? Maybe in your view?